# toolbar title show at bottom

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I use coordinator layout when I scroll up image collapsed and title shows up.

but a problem is in some mobile it shows at the bottom.

[image]

here is XML code of my .......................................................................................................

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.donation.bhatt.donation.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/mainwindow"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/maintoolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:gravity="top"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: remove appbarlayout and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**now set the title of your toolbar like this**

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
 mTitle.setText("title");
```

Comment: my reputation is less than 15 so StackOverflow doesn't allow me to upvote. sorry for that :(

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use expandedTitleGravity flag available for CollapsingToolbarLayout  to set the title gravity to centre horizontal